# Obtaining analytical solutions of an equation

Tags: equation-solving

Let's define a couple of equations

```
x0 = 1/2;
r0 = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
r1 = Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + y^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x + x0)^2 + y^2];
fc = 2*(1 + 4*b);

Ω = 1/fc*(b/r0 + 1/r1 + 1/r2) + ω^2/2*(x^2 + y^2);

Ωx = D[Ω, x];
Ωx0 = Ωx /. {y -> 0};
```

I know that the equation $\Omega_{x0} = 0$ has four roots. Two positive and two negative. In fact, the roots are $\pm x_1$ and $\pm x_2$.

When I try

```
sol = Solve[Ωx0 == 0, x]
```

the program runs forever without giving any results. So, is there a clever way or a trick to obtain the analytical solutions of this equation? Note, that I do not want numerical solutions. I am looking for the analytical solutions which are functions of $b$ and $\omega$.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using `D` as a variable.

Comment: @Feyre Oops! Corrected.

Comment: I suspect this can only be done numerically. The closest I can come is `Interpolation` of numeric answers.

Comment: @Feyre Can you show how you obtained the numerical solutions?

Comment: Depending on the relative magnitude of b and omega, your best option may be to seek a series solution. Are they small or known approximately?

Comment: @mikado $b$ varies in the interval $[0,100]$, while $\omega$ in the interval $(0,5]$.

Comment: Turns out programmatically separating `x1` and `x2` is a bit of a hindrance.